# How do I print certain parts of a string array?

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that dumps a file into octal. After it reaches the limit for amount of characters on a line, it is suppose to print out the printable characters of file being passed into.

For some reason my program always prints the first 16 characters of the text file, how would i print the rest of the characters in the file?

Here is the text file i'm using to test:

```
 ?asdfadsbgasdfassadfasdfsadfads
 asdf
 asdf
 asd
 v
 asdf
 asdf
 asd
 f
 asdf
```

Here is the output to stdout:

```
   0000000 77 141 163 144 146 141 144 163 142 147 141 163 144 146 141 163  | ?asdfadsbgasdfas
   0000020 163 141 144 146 141 163 144 146 163 141 144 146 141 144 163 15  | ?asdfadsbgasdfas
   0000040 12 141 163 144 146 15 12 141 163 144 146 15 12 141 163 144  | ?asdfadsbgasdfas
   0000060 15 12 166 15 12 141 163 144 146 15 12 141 163 144 146 15  | ?asdfadsbgasdfas
   0000100 12 141 163 144 15 12 146 15 12 141 163 144 146 15 12 ?asdfadsbgasdfa
   0000120
```

Here is my code:

```
void octaldump(FILE * fp)
{
    int c;
    size_t linecount = 0, index = 0, i;
    long int address = 0;
    char temp [LINESIZE];

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(linecount == 0)
        {
            printf("%07o ", address);
            address += 16;
        }
        temp[index] = c;
        index++;

        printf("%02o ", c);
        linecount++;

        if(linecount == 16)
        {
            printf(" | ");
            for(i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
            {
                if(temp[i] <= 32)
                {
                    printf(".");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", temp[i]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            linecount = 0;
        }
    }

    if(linecount < 16)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
        {
            if(temp[i] <= 32)
            {
                printf(".");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", temp[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n%07o ", address);
}
```

Comment: You'd get better laid out output if you use `"%03o"` instead of `"%02o"`.  You could also look up `isprint()` in `<ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you don't set `index` back to zero after the `linecount == 16` code. Amongst other things, that means you have a horrendous buffer overflow.

In the trailing data processing, you should first print out enough blanks for the missing characters that the printable characters are aligned with the other sets.  I mentioned in a comment using `"%03o"` in place of `"%02o"` to give consistent alignment.  Also, using `isprint()` from `<ctype.h>` would improve things.

---

This works reasonably well for me - tested on its own source code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { LINESIZE = 16 };

void octaldump(FILE * fp)
{
    int c;
    size_t linecount = 0, index = 0, i;
    unsigned long address = 0;
    char temp [LINESIZE];

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (linecount == 0)
        {
            printf("%07lo ", address);
            address += 16;
        }
        temp[index] = c;
        index++;

        printf("%03o ", c);
        linecount++;

        if (linecount == 16)
        {
            printf(" | ");
            for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
                printf("%c", isprint(temp[i]) ? temp[i] : '.');
            printf("\n");
            linecount = 0;
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    if (linecount < 16)
    {
        for (int j = linecount; j < 16; j++)
            printf("    ");
        printf(" | ");

        for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
            printf("%c", isprint(temp[i]) ? temp[i] : '.');
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("%07lo\n", address);
}

int main(void)
{
    octaldump(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The full-length lines of output are 91 characters long. If you use hex instead of octal, you can easily get lines of just 74 characters long, which is often more convenient.  Just for fun, you should work out how to suppress repeated lines of data like `od` does.